# Parse this date format?

Tags: c#, .net, pdf

I have this date format from a PDF file with `D:` before the date `20170328092616+01'00'` and I'm trying to parse this format.

```
DateTime parsedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(
    "D:20170328092616+01'00'",
    "0:yyyyMMddhhmmss",
    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
    DateTimeStyles.None);
```

However, the code throws a `FormatException`. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Thats nice for you - what is the post about?

Comment: @BugFinder trying to understand this fromat so i can get the date

Comment: But you already have the string outlining the format..

Comment: What´s so hard about it? The format stands behind, it means four characters for the year followed by two characters for month, two for day, two for hour, two for minute, two for seconds. The +1 is the time-zone you´re in, meaning GMT + 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your date string has a weird format. This works:

```
Console.Write(DateTime.ParseExact("20170328092616+01:00", "yyyyMMddhhmmsszzz", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is [DateTimeOffset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/choosing-between-datetime): DateTime with timezone info.

```
var offset = DateTimeOffset.Now.ToString("D:yyyyMMddhhmmsszzzz"); // this produces "D:20170926114506+02:00"
 var parsedDate = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(offset, "D:yyyyMMddhhmmsszzzz", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

You have to find proper CultureInfo, or replace ' with : in the timezone part

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is that the time zone of the string cannot be parsed using `DateTime.ParseExact` because it contains quotes. However, you can remove the quotes to make it parsable. At the same time you might as well get rid of the leading `D:` even though these extra characters doesn't make it impossible to parse the timestamp.

```
"D:20170328092616+01'00'".Substring(2).Replace("'", "")
```

You should also use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` instead of `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`. You don't know what the later is and there might be cases where a culture will be unable to parse the timestamp.

Notice that the format specificer `hh` is for 12 hours format and I'm pretty sure that you want `HH` for 24 hours format. Otherwise you need AM/PM in the timestamp.

Putting all this together you get:

```
DateTime parsedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(
    "D:20170328092616+01'00'".Substring(2).Replace("'", ""),
    "yyyyMMddHHmmsszzzz",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
    DateTimeStyles.None);
```

You should be aware that the kind of the parsed date is `Local` which means that `parsedDate` is converted to the local time zone whatever that is (the timestamp contains an offset so it is well defined). Depending on how you intend to use the parsed date you might be better of by parsing to kind `Utc`. You can do that by using `DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal` instead of `DateTimeStyles.None`. Or you can switch to using a `DateTimeOffset` instead of a `DateTime` which will preserve the original offset (+01:00).